# I want to show the child element lower than the parent element but z-index in negative is behaving improperly in safari

Tags: html, css

z-index in negative is behaving improperly only in safari. is there any way to make the parent element upper than the child element using z-index?

Comment: Not enough information to go on. Please show us your HTML & CSS/

Comment: finally got it working through jquery. Negative z-index is really a problem in safari browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `z-index` you should also apply the `position` property. Set it to `relative or absolute` Whatever is needed. The inherited display value is not enough for the browser to use z-index properly.

Comment: I'm already using position absolute and z-index negative to the child element but it's not working properly in safari

Comment: The parent **must** have been set to `position:relative` (or absolute) for z-index to work.

Comment: i'm using position with the parent also but not the z-index. on adding z-index the parent is upper than the child whatever the case

Comment: like i said i'm using already what you've told but it's not working properly only in safari

Comment: 1 and 2 are not helping with that only -1 is helpful in in what i want

Comment: @NickySmits You do not required to set a z-index on the parent in order to achieve what op is trying to do.  Also, negative z-index values are valid.